# Variável contador PHP

Tags: php, html, variáveis, contador

Boas pessoal,

Eu tenho um *form* num ficheiro *PHP* para preencher uma tabela de classificações. E queria que o meu *form* pergunta-se algo do género, "Numero do atleta na posição ___", onde ficasse o numero da posição no __.

Por exemplo: O *form* vai começar assim "Qual o numero do atleta no 1º lugar" e depois preenche-mos o *form* e clicamos *submit* depois de clicar o *form* vai aparecer assim "Qual o numero do atleta no 2º lugar" e voltamos a clicar "Qual o numero do atleta no 3º lugar" e por ai adiante. Mas quando sairmos do browser voltar ao sitio onde ficou, se o *form* ficar a "Qual o numero do atleta no 5º lugar" e se fecharmos o browser quando voltamos ao site o *form* ficar no mesmo sitio.

E eu sou mais dado a Java portanto eu pensava que podia fazer uma variável tipo contador. Mas não sei fazer e fui pesquisar e não encontrei nada útil.

Alguém sabe fazer isso em *PHP* ou sabe fazer algo parecido que me possa indicar um site ou o que fazer?

Ai está meu *form*

```html
<div id="formT">
 <form  method="post" action="alterarN.php">
  <p>Qual e o Dorsal do atleta em _º lugar?</p>
       <!--nesse _ deve estar o lugar-->
  <p><input type="text"  name="numero" required/></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Registar" id="registar"/>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Posta teu código ai Bruno, pra podermos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: @DiegoSantos já tem código ai.

Comment: o contador deve persistir por sessão do navegador? por usuário? deve ser global?

Comment: @Sanção o contador deve persitir pelo numero de atleta se inserir na base de dados

Comment: Vc quer criar um combo, as posições dos atletas p selecionar?

Comment: @rray  O que eu quero é que no meu *form* à medida que eu insiro atletas, o "___" do "Qual o numero do atleta que ficou em __º lugar" vá mudando. Por exemplo: "Qual o numero do atleta que ficou em 1º lugar" e eu insiro o numero e quando fizer *submit* mude para "Qual o numero do atleta que ficou em 2º lugar" e por ai adiante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql_select_db($bd, $coneccao);

$query = "SELECT lugar FROM atletas";
$result = mysql_query($query, $coneccao) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$lugar = row['lugar'];
$lugar+=1;


<div id="formT">
    <form  method="post" action="alterarN.php">
        <p>Qual e o Dorsal do atleta em <?php echo $lugar; ?>º lugar?</p>
       <!--nesse _ deve estar o lugar-->
        <p><input type="text"  name="numero" required/></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Registar" id="registar"/>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Faltou incrementar 1 a variável `$lugar` e também setar 0 caso o retorno da query seja null.

Comment: `Editado!`  Não testei, mas se for `null` e fizer `$lugar+=1;` o valor passa a ser 1, teoricamente.